In Exodus 3 & 4, when Moses confronts the Angel of God, does the Angel speak on God's behalf, God through the Angel, or is the Angel himself also God?
Exodus 3:2, 3:4-6 ESV

The Angel of YHWH appeared to him in a flame of fire out of
the midst of a bush.
When YHWH saw that he turned aside to see, God called to him out
of the bush, “Moses, Moses!” And he said, “Here I am.” Then he said,
“Do not come near; take your sandals off your feet, for the place on
which you are standing is holy ground.” And he said, “I am the God of
your father, the God of Abraham, the God of Isaac, and the God of
Jacob.” And Moses hid his face, for he was afraid to look at God.

There are many other instances of the Angel of YHWH speaking as God throughout Scripture.
Hebrews 1:1-2 ESV

Long ago, at many times and in many ways, God spoke to our fathers by
the prophets, but in these last days he has spoken to us by his Son,
whom he appointed the heir of all things, through whom also he created
the world.

Does the Angel speak as he does because:

The Angel speaks on behalf of God as his representative who wields the divine Name?

Or,

The Angel is the one through whom God speaks via the Spirit's possession of his body?

Or,

The Angel speaks as God because he is quite literally also God along with the Father?


I'm not going to vote to close even though I think this question is "opinion-based". If we closed all the questions that involve theological opinions as well has hermeneutical analysis, most of the interesting questions would disappear. @OneGodOneLord... would you like to provide an answer yourself?

@DanFefferman – Yes, I personally believe in position #1, namely that the Angel has the authority to speak as God despite not being himself God, as the Angel is God's representative who wields the divine Name on behalf of God as his mediator.

@OneGodOneLord. God is not an angel. He is God. There no reason why God will call Himself the angel of God.

@AlexBalilo, I am on your side. There is only one God, the Father, and one Lord of man, the Son Jesus Christ.

It's a good question and your point number 3 is the correct answer so let me explain. But first let's define terms. The Hebrew word for angel is "malak' and it simply means "messenger." For example at Malachi 3:1, "Behold I am going to send My "malak, angel, messenger" and he will clear the way before Me. And the Lord, whom you seek, will suddenly come to His temple, and the "malak, angel, messenger" of the covenant, in whom you delight, behold He is coming, says the Lord of hosts."
The first angel/messenger who clears the way of the Lord is John the Baptist. This is verified at Mark 1:1-4. The second angel/messenger of the covenant is the pre-incarnate Jesus Christ also known as "the angel of the Lord." My point being in this little exercise is to show that even men are called angels/messengers as well actual angels like for instance Michael. As a side note the name of the book "Malachi," well his name is from the root word "malak."
The angel of the Lord first appears as the angel of the Lord at Genesis 16:7. And he says in the following verses that he will multiply Hagar's descendants at verse 10. At verse 13 Hagar says, "Thou art a God who sees; Have I even remained alive after seeing Him."
At Genesis 17:1-2 you have the Lord appearing to Abram and said to him, "I am God Almighty; Walk before Me, and be blameless. verse 2, And I will establish My covenant between Me and you, And I will multiply your exceedingly."
Going to Genesis 22:1 it says, "Now it came about after these things, that God tested Abraham etc." At verse 11, "But the angel of the Lord called to him/Abraham from heaven, AND SAID, Abraham, Abraham! etc." verse 12, "Do not stretch out your hand against the lad, and do nothing to him, for now I KNOW that you fear God, since you have not WITHHELD your son, your only son, FROM ME."
Verse 15, "Then the angel of the Lord called to Abraham a second time from heaven, verse 16, AND SAID, "By Myself I have sworn, declares the Lord, because you have done this thing, and have not withheld your son, your only son, verse 17, "indeed I will greatly multiply your seed as the starts of the heavens, and as the sand which is on the seashore; and your seed shall possess the gate of their enemies." Verse 18, "And in your seed all the nations of the earth shall be blessed because YOU HAVE OBEYED MY VOICE."
So what we have here is the angel of the Lord at Genesis 16 who multiplied Hagar's descendants and was identified as God is the same being who made the covenant to Abram at Genesis 17:1-2 who is identified as God. It is also the same being (the angel of the Lord) at Genesis 22:16-18.
All of this is backed up by the writer of Hebrews at Hebrews 6:13-14, "For when God made the promise to Abraham, since He could swear by no one greater, HE SWORE BY HIMSELF, Verse 14, "saying, I will surely bless you, and I will surely multiply you." At Luke 1:73, "The oath which He swore to Abraham our father."
A couple of points of interest. The angel of the Lord is speaking in the "first person" here. This is confirmed at (Genesis 16:10, Genesis 21:18, Genesis 31:13). Also the angel of the Lord appears at, Genesis 16:7-14, Genesis 22:11-16, Exodus 3:2-4, (the burning bush), Numbers 22:22-38, Judges 2:1-3 and at other places.
Also note, that the angel of the Lord never appears in the New Testament, although he is mentioned at Acts 7. Another important point that people miss is there is a difference between the words, "a or an" as opposed to the word "the." For example, some will say the angel of the Lord appeared to Joseph at Matthew 1:20 and say "the angle of the Lord appeared etc. despite the fact that the word used is "an" angel of the Lord appeared.
The grammatical function of "an" or "a" is to connote a thing not previously noted or recognized. In other words, it's just that, an angel/messenger. The word "the" connotes a thing PREVIOUSLY noted or recognized, i.e "THE angel of the Lord. Finally, the Biblical evidence clearly points out the angel of the Lord is the preincarnate Jesus Christ.
Remember, God the Father cannot be seen and the Father has no separate manifestation from the Son. The Son is the only manifestation and revelation of the Father. What is known of the Father is revealed through the Son. To see the Son is to see the essence of the Father, John 1:18, John 10:30, John 12:45, Colossians 1:15, Hebrews 1:3.
I have one more point to make and it's from Deuteronomy 7:6-8 and the Lord God is speaking and He explains why God chose Israel. I will just high light the main points to make a point. At vs8, The Lord God chose you because the Lord loved you and kept the oath which He swore to your forefathers, the Lord brought you out by a mighty hand, and redeemed you from the house of slavery, from the hand of Pharaoh king of Egypt.
Now, here is what Judges 2:1 states, "Now the angel of the Lord came up from Gilgal to Bochim. And he said, "I brought you up out of Egypt and led you into the land which I have sworn to your fathers; and I said, I will never break My covenant with you." The Lord God always keeps His promises.

John 12:49-50 – "I have not spoken on My own, but the Father who sent Me has commanded Me what to say and how to say it. And I know that His command leads to eternal life. So I speak exactly what the Father has told Me to say.”

What your forgetting is Hebrews 1:1-3 "God, after He spoke long ago to the fathers in the prophets in many ways vs2, in these last days has spoken t5o us in His Son, whom He appointed heir of all things, through whom also He made the world. Vs3, "And He is the radiance  of His glory and the exact representation of His nature, (that is the Fathers nature), and upholds all things by the word of His power. When He had made purification of sins. He sat down at the right of the Majesty on high." In these last days refers to Jesus appearing as the suffering servant, the Messiah, hence John 12:49-50

Mr.Bond, Hebrews 1 is saying that God speaks to us through his Son, which means that the Son says exactly what the Father tells him to say, as God's representative.

I get all that but that does not preclude the Son in the OT as the angel of the Lod in the form of a theophany which is a manifestation of God tangible to the human senses. I already be proved in my main post that Jesus is God. And you  have not refuted one word of my post, why? Did you even read it all and check the references to see if they are true? Read Acts 17:11.

Mr.Bond – Where in scripture does Jesus ever plainly declare that he is God? He only declared to be the firstborn Son of God.

Mr.Bond, the Son has the authority to speak and swear as God only because he has been given the authority by God as God to wield the Tetragrammaton Name.

That's like saying I saw the man murder his wife and I'm willing to send my Uncle Harry into court (because I'm in the hospital) and he can swear to it? I also suggest you read Hebrews 6:13-18. Vs13, "He swore BY HIMESLF. vs 16, "For men swear by one greater than themselves, and with them an oath given as confirmation is THE END OF THE DIALOGUE." Vs17, "In the same way, God desiring even more to show to the heirs of the promise the UNCHANGEABLENESS of His purpose, interposed with an oath." Read Revelation 10:5-6 where an actual angel swore by Him who lives forever and ever."

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The angel of the LORD (מַלְאַךְ יְהוָה) is a visible manifestation of the unvisible God.

"The word angel arrives in modern English from Old English engel and
the Old French angele. Both of these derive from Late Latin angelus,
which in turn was borrowed from Late Greek ἄγγελος angelos (literally
"messenger"). The rendering of ángelos is the Septuagint's default
translation of the Biblical Hebrew term malʼākh, denoting simply
"messenger" without connoting its nature. In the Latin Vulgate, this
meaning becomes bifurcated: when malʼākh or ángelos is supposed to
denote a human messenger, words like nuntius or legatus are applied.
If the word refers to some supernatural being, the word angelus
appears. Such differentiation has been taken over by later vernacular
translations of the Bible, early Christian and Jewish exegetes and
eventually modern scholars."

Firstly than, messenger is a job description.
Additionally, no creature sent by God would accept being worshipped by men. Only the Creator Himself would allow that to take place.

8 I, John, am the one who heard and saw these things. And when I had
heard and seen them, I fell down to worship at the feet of the angel
who had been showing them to me. 9 But he said to me, “Don’t do that!
I am a fellow servant with you and with your fellow prophets and with
all who keep the words of this scroll. Worship God!” (Revelation 22)
1 The Lord appeared to Abraham near the great trees of Mamre while he
was sitting at the entrance to his tent in the heat of the day. 2
Abraham looked up and saw three men standing nearby. When he saw them,
he hurried from the entrance of his tent to meet them and bowed low to
the ground. 3 He said, “If I have found favor in your eyes, my lord,
do not pass your servant by. (Abraham says that to a single person,
the one he bowed to.) 4 Let a little water be brought, and then you
may all wash your feet and rest under this tree. 5Let me get you
something to eat, so you can be refreshed and then go on your way—now
that you have come to your servant.” “Very well,” they answered, “do
as you say.” … 13 Then the Lord said to Abraham, “Why did Sarah laugh
and say, ‘Will I really have a child, now that I am old?’ 14 Is
anything too hard for the Lord? I will return to you at the appointed
time next year, and Sarah will have a son.” (Genesis 18)
13 Now when Joshua was near Jericho, he looked up and saw a man
standing in front of him with a drawn sword in his hand. Joshua went
up to him and asked, “Are you for us or for our enemies?” 14
“Neither,” he replied, “but as commander of the army of the Lord I
have now come.” Then Joshua fell facedown to the ground in reverence,
and asked him, “What message does my Lord have for his servant?” 15
The commander of the Lord’s army replied, “Take off your sandals, for
the place where you are standing is holy.” And Joshua did so. (Joshua
5)
(In Numbers 22, 2 Samuel 24  and 1 Chronicles 21 the same being is
called the angel of the LORD.)
5 “Do not come any closer,” God said. “Take off your sandals, for the
place where you are standing is holy ground.”
(What made the ground
holy was God's presence. The commandment given to Aaron, to wash his
hands and feet before entering barefoot the Holy of Holies on the Day
of Atonement, follows the same logic.)

Since the angel of the LORD allowed men to worship him, he has to be God Himself.

You say, "Since the Angel of the LORD allowed men to worship him, he has to be God Himself". I disagree. The Angel of God wields the divine Name within himself, and as such, he has the authority to speak on behalf of God as though he is God, despite being God as God's Son.

Is that so? We know that in the OT, angels are collectively called sons of God/Elohim. But this is different. Give me, one quote from the OT where God calls a single angel His son.

5 For to which of the angels did God ever say, “You are my Son; today I have become your Father”? Or again, “I will be his Father, and he will be my Son”? 6 And again, when God brings his firstborn into the world, he says, “Let all God’s angels worship him.” (Hebrews 1)
